# Show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}|M_n|=|\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}M_n|$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, elementary-set-theory

> Let be $(M_n)$ a monotone **increasing** sequence of sets, i.e. $M_n\subseteq M_{n+1}$, with $M_n\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}M_n=\mathbb{N}$. Show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}|M_n|=|\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}M_n|$. (Hint: $|\cdot|$ denotes the cardinality)

---

**My approach:**

Clearly, $|\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}M_n|=|\mathbb{N}|=\infty$.

Next, we choose an arbitrary $c>0$, since $(M_n)$ is increasing we find a set $M_{n_0}$ that is "large" enough such that $|M_{n_0}| >c$. Again, due to monotonicity all subsequent members of $(M_n)$ must have a larger cardinality. Hence, for all $n>n_0$ we have $|(M_n)|\geq c$ which is the definition of $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}|M_n|=\infty$. Finally, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}|M_n|=|\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}M_n|=\infty$.

I am not sure if one needs more knowledge on set theory or if this problem can be simply approached with tools from calculus like I did. May be I am mixing concepts falsely.

Another question, what if $(M_n)$ was not monotone? Is the statement $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}|M_n|=|\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}M_n|$ still valid?

Comment: If $M_n$ is not monotonic then $\lim M_n$ might not be exist as a set.

Comment: What is the definition of $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} M_n$?